# how to programatically increase the JVM on android to 10MB?

Tags: android, jvm, out-of-memory

is it possible to programatically increase the JVM android machine to 10MB? If yes can someone post a java code and let me know how to do it? I have a file of 11MB and I get the error out of memory when I try to parse the file in a string. Need help. appreciate

UPDATE:

I've also parse with SAX. Same result. When adding android:largeHeap=true I have error: No resource identifier found for attribute LargeHeap
Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you answer, what exactly you trying to do?

If your app targets at honeycomb (android 3.0) and later you can try to set option 
android:largeHeap="true" in Application tag of your AndroidManifest.xml.

If you trying to parse JSON or XML, try to streaming aproach instead of tree-based.

UPDATE:
In AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
<application android:largeHeap="true">
   ...
</application>
...
```

You are lucky if have a rooted phone. You can try change line

```
dalvik.vm.heapsize=24m
```

in /system/build.props.

If not, you can try to use the SAX library to parse your XML content. It can help to avoid to load full file at time, instead with this library you can load your data by small pieces.

ALSO: There are no JVM on android. There is Dalvik.

Comment: I want to increase android runtime heap memoty to 20MB.

Comment: i am paring with ksoap a 11 MB file. I have the error out of memory.

Comment: how to set android:largeHeap="true"?

Comment: is there a way to keep in a string value just a half of the returned string size, and in another string the rest of the parse